# how to add gridview with objectdatasource in code behind c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create gridview with code. My code is:

```
 GridView gdvList = new GridView();
 gdvList.ID = "gdvList" ;
 TemplateField tField = new TemplateField();
 BoundField dateBF = new BoundField();
 dateBF.DataField = "Date";
 gdvList.Columns.Add(dateBF);
 BoundField countResponse = new BoundField();
 countResponse.DataField = "CountResponse";
 gdvList.Columns.Add(countResponse);
 ObjectDataSource ods = new ObjectDataSource();
 ods.ID = "ods";
 ods.TypeName = "Project.BLLQuestion";
 ods.SelectMethod = "GetByGroupID";
 ods.SelectParameters["GroupID"] = new Parameter("inGroupID", DbType.Int32, "0");
 ods.DataBind();
 gdvList.DataSource = ods;
 gdvList.DataBind();
```

this code does not work, and how to add TemplateField do :

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItemTemplateField">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <a href="Question.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ID")%>"><%# Eval("Content").ToString().PadRight(140).Substring(0,140).TrimEnd()+"..." %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

how can do it?

Comment: Why you would like to generate a grid from code?

Comment: we have group dynamically.so we need it

Comment: Then why not use repeater instead..?

Comment: i dont add all code.

Comment: Where is this code being run? Page_Load? Somewhere else?

Comment: button clicked code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to set `DataSourceID` property of Grid, not `DataSource`.
2. There are no need to run `DataBind()` method of `ObjectDataSource`.
3. Ensure that both controls `ObjectDataSource` and `GridView` are added on `Page`.

Try this:

```
  ObjectDataSource ods = new ObjectDataSource();
  ods.ID = "ods";
  ods.TypeName = "Project.BLLQuestion";
  ods.SelectMethod = "GetByGroupID";
  ods.SelectParameters["GroupID"] = new Parameter("inGroupID", DbType.Int32, "0");

  Page.Controls.Add(ods);

  GridView gdvList = new GridView();
  gdvList.ID = "gdvList" ;
  gdvList.DataSourceID = "ods";

  BoundField dateBF = new BoundField();
  dateBF.DataField = "Date";
  gdvList.Columns.Add(dateBF);

  BoundField countResponse = new BoundField();
  countResponse.DataField = "CountResponse";
  gdvList.Columns.Add(countResponse);

  Page.Controls.Add(gdvList);

  gdvList.DataBind();
```

According to your second question. Try to replace `TemplateField` by `HyperLinkField`. Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.